# making graph openpyxl categories not selected

Tags: python, excel, graph, openpyxl

I'm trying to make a graph and use a column of my excel sheet to be categories label. I have run .set_categories and it returns a correct '=Sheet!$A1:$A12' str. But the resulting Graph does not use the categories and just labels the graph with numbers.
Resizing the graph doesn't work. 
I have tried including 'A' in my data variable. But it includes the classnames as a series, and only once i edit the graph, flip the axis and then flip back... it does... 
Can someone take a look at my code and see if there is anythng obvious. Thanks

```
#Add chart to Worksheet
chart = BarChart()

#chart.add_data(values)
cats = Reference(ws1, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_col=1, max_row=p+1)
print(cats)
data = Reference(ws1, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=3, max_row=p+1)
chart.set_categories(cats)
chart.x_axis.tickLblSkip = 1 #test
chart.add_data(data=data, titles_from_data=True) #test
chart.type = "bar"
chart.style = 10
chart.grouping = "percentStacked"
chart.overlap = 100
chart.title = 'Classes Visualised'
ws1.add_chart(chart, "E15")
```

[pic of resulting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RimJV.png)

Answer (score 2):

So i worked it out. For anyone in the future who is as confused.
The order of Data and Categories is important.
Solution is

```
chart.add_data(data=data, titles_from_data=True) #1
chart.set_categories(cats) #2
```